# Temporary whose address is used as value of local variable 'pr' will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression (C++)?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine-5

А в чем тут ошибка?
Возникла после обновления на версию движка 5.2.
Локальная переменная pr будет уничтожена после завершения выражения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: 'These macros use a class instance declared in local scope and allocate space on the stack, so it is very important you do not retain pointers to them! They are intended only for passing strings to function calls.' [Conversion Routines](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/UnrealArchitecture/StringHandling/CharacterEncoding/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял TCHAR_TO_UTF8 это специальный макрос который освободит выделенную под строку память сразу после ";" поэтому указатель pr окажется висящим. Ошибка возникла вероятнее всего потому что с новой версией добавили больше проверок на подобные ошибки в коде. Использование макросов непосредственно в выражении где используются указатели должно решить проблему.

Об этом говорится в документации:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

[Макрос `TCHAR_TO_UTF8`](https://github.com/amyvmiwei/UnrealEngine4/blob/dcedd04201bbdb19ee456a75e3c15b31cb2b154f/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Containers/StringConv.h#L575C1-L575C76) создаёт внутри себя объект типа `FTCHARToUTF8` и возвращает указатель на внутреннюю память этого объекта:

```
#define TCHAR_TO_UTF8(str) (ANSICHAR*)FTCHARToUTF8((const TCHAR*)str).Get()
```

Время жизни анонимного объекта типа `FTCHARToUTF8` до конца statement-а. Соответственно, в строке `595` вашего кода этот объект уже не существует, и указатель `pr` указывает в память с неопределённым содержимым.

Если не использовать временную переменную `pr`, то ошибка должна исчезнуть:

```
const chat * getItem = element->Attribute(TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*attrName));
```

В этом случае временный объект будет существовать до завершения вызова функции, и временный указатель, возвращенный методом `Get`, будет валиден.

Вот пример висящей ссылки:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    private:
      int x;
    public:
      A(int x) : x(x) {
        cout << "A(" << x << ")" << endl;
      }
      ~A() {
        cout << "~A(" << x << ")" << endl;
      }
      int* get() { return &x; }
};

class B {
    private:
      int* ptr;
    public:
      B(int* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {
        cout << "B(&" << *ptr << ")" << endl;
      }
      ~B() {
        cout << "~B(&" << *ptr << ")" << endl;
      }
      int* get() { return ptr; }
      int operator * () { return *ptr; }
};

#define Z(x) (A((x)).get())

int main() {
    {
        int x = 42;
        cout << "Before Z" << endl;
        B y = Z(x);
        cout << "After Z" << endl;
        cout << "*y = " << *y << endl;
    }
    cout << "The end!";
    return 0;
}
```

```
Before Z
A(42)
B(&42)
~A(42)
After Z
*y = 42
~B(&42)
```

Внутри макроса `Z` создаётся объект типа `A`. Этот объект существует до конца инициализации `B y`, сразу после инициазации уничтожается. Поэтому `y.ptr` указывает на уже освобождённую память. В этом примере, вообще говоря, повезло, что память не испортилась.

Если `main` немного подкрутить, добавив дополнительные переменные, то содержимое `y` необратимо портится:

```
int main() {
    {
        int x = 42;
        cout << "Before Z" << endl;
        B y = Z(x);
        cout << "After Z" << endl;
        int zero = 0;
        B b_zero = &zero;
        cout << "*y = " << *y << endl;
        cout << "*b_zero = " << *b_zero << endl;
    }
    cout << "The end!";
    return 0;
}
```

```
Before Z
A(42)
B(&42)
~A(42)
After Z
B(&0)
*y = -341712064
*b_zero = 0
~B(&0)
~B(&-341712064)
```